# PHP - Load a webproperty by id in google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

I'm using [Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)

I know that I can get all the account with the following:

```
$oAnalytics = getService(); //Analytics service object
$oAccounts = $oAnalytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
```

But it is too much work to go through every account and property to find the `defaultProfileId` I want.

I'd like to load the entire Webproperties class by the id ('UA-00000000')

Is there a function or method to Webproperties by id?

Comment: What library do you use for GA? `getService()` should return you an object of some class.

Comment: It's not what I'm asking about. What `PHP` tool do you use to communicate with that API? What does `getService()` return to you?

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list) there's no such filter. The only parameters you can pass are:

> Optional query parameters
>
> **max-results** *integer*   The maximum number of
>   accounts to include in this response.
>
> **start-index**    *integer*   An index of
>   the first account to retrieve. Use this parameter as a pagination
>   mechanism along with the max-results parameter.

But you can create a wrapper function over the resulting accounts array and filter it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

While digging through the Class `Google_Service_Analytics_ManagementWebproperties_Resource` I found a method that solved my problem.

Class `Google_Service_Analytics_ManagementWebproperties_Resource` has a method `get`.

`get` returns a `Google_Service_Analytics_Webproperty` to which the user has access to. The method has 2 required parameters: `$accountId` and `$webPropertyId`.

```
$oAnalytics = getService(); //getService returns a Analytics service object
$foo = $oAnalytics->management_webproperties->get(\**ACCOUNT_ID**,\**WEB_PROPERTY_ID**);
```